# How much energy does cache memory consume in a modern processor?

Tags: power, microprocessor, energy, cache

What fraction (on average or range) of total processor energy consumption does the cache subsystem consume in modern processors (say post 2009)?

Comment: 0 < CachePwr < 100%

Comment: Why are you asking this? This is an incredibly difficult question to answer in any kind of general sense because 'a modern processor' still pertains to at least tens of different SRAM designs.

Comment: Unless you've got a specific workload idea, and a specific processor, the closest you'll get is about Michael Karas's answer. Even if you do get that specific, the answer will come from a simulation or experimental run.

Comment: Caches consume 16% and 30% of total power in Alpha 21264 and StrongARM, respectively. L2 cache consumes ~24% of total power in both Niagara and Niagara-2. Here is the [reference](https://goo.gl/XCXGpE). This is a valid question and may be reopened; many papers do present this data.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a numerical answer but, you can get some idea from the following [Intel presentation of Ivy Bridge](http://www.hotchips.org/wp-content/uploads/hc_archives/hc24/HC24-1-Microprocessor/HC24.28.117-HotChips_IvyBridge_Power_04.pdf).

First the photo of the die colored by functional areas:
[image]

The area to right of the (green) cores is the L3 cache (LLC = last level cache, in Intelspeak). Then here are the IREM (infrared emission, thus heat) photos of the die:
[image]

I suppose if you knew the (unpublished) temperature scale, then you could reverse engineer the relative power of the areas. There's a full [video of the talk on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GXA38vFPXA#t=751) but it doesn't add much info for this particular question. One interesting tidbit is that the cores' power plane is gated, but the L3 cache is not, so when the die is almost entirely off, the L3 cache seems to use the most power.

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult question to answer, because like most processor metrics it depends on the actual workload. [If we take a look at this die shot of an Intel i7](http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow_viewer/0,3253,l=258561&a=258561&po=2,00.asp) we can see that the L3 cache is about 30% of the area, and I estimate that the highly regular structures at the bottom of each core are L2 and L1 cache. That puts cache at about 50% of the area. So to a very rough approximation it will be consuming 50% of the power.

Again, this depends on workload. It's possible to power down 3 of the 4 cores while the L3 cache must be kept active. Some workloads (lots of task swapping) are prone to cache flushing and the cores will be stalled most of the time while the cache is working.

However, at any one time most of the cache is idle, just retaining data takes less energy than changing state. A computation-heavy load will draw much more from the cores than the cache. I'd ballpark cache as 25% of the power consumption when all four cores are loaded.

(Intel will have their own design estimates for these numbers, which will be trade secrets. It's quite hard to *measure* seperately even by decapping the chip, but simulation should give them reasonable numbers.)